# Building Mobile API, more HTTP requests vs length of data

Tags: android, ios, cakephp, windows-phone-8, blackberry-10

Concerning performance on the modern smartphone OSs i.e WP8, Android, IOS, BlackBerry 10.
Building mobile API JSON Object based, between more HTTP requests and length of data returned which one takes a higher priority to optimize your native app performance?

I have cakephp backend generation JSON results with mysql database.

Comment: This question is basically pointless. You don't know nothing about the available bandwidth on mobile clients, because it all depends on the client's data plan and also on available quality of the network. It's simply no question of performance, you always have to prepare for poor connections when targeting mobile clients.

Comment: The reason I'm asking this is for preparation for poor connections, I was debating with my team on this. I'm looking at performance of the native apps even on the lowest bandwidth i.e 2G network internet connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out http://developer.android.com/training/efficient-downloads/efficient-network-access.html#ReduceConnections --> "Rather than creating multiple simultaneous connections to download data, or chaining multiple consecutive GET requests, where possible you should bundle those requests into a single GET."

Comment: I was actually looking at making one GET request for getting minimal data and making another request after the first one has completed whenever the user request to view additional data. or making one request for once with all data catering for when for when user wants to view addition data that they won't have to make another GET request. Like between these two which one would be more efficient?

Comment: It all depends on your UI. Is minimal data enough to have functional UI for the user?  If yes, then it makes sense to do that as a separate call, that will come back quicker on weaker connection (as less data to transfer). Make sure you read the whole page I linked to, loads of interesting information about how radio cell works.